# How to properly configure Paging to work in 64-bit mode?

Tags: assembly, operating-system, x86-64, nasm, virtual-memory

I created 4 KiB pages:

```
section .bss
align 4096
page_map_level_4:
    resb 4096
page_directory_pointer_table:
    resb 4096
page_directory:
    resb 4096
page_table:
    resb 4096
```

I then wrote a subroutine to set links from page to page:

```
setup_paging:
    mov eax, page_directory_pointer_table
    or eax, 0b11
    mov [page_map_level_4], eax

    mov eax, page_directory
    or eax, 0b11
    mov [page_directory_pointer_table], eax

    mov eax, page_table
    or eax, 0b11
    mov [page_directory], eax

    mov eax, page_map_level_4
    mov cr3, eax

    ret
```

I'm completely new to this, so I'm researching the OSDev Wiki and the way I've written it could be wrong. I want to make sure and learn how to do it right.